# read / write on byte array by QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, qdatastream

i have byte image array i want to write this byte array to another byte array with add some another value on second byte array , i'm using this code but i think something is wrong

```
 QByteArray byteArray;

 QDataStream ds(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadWrite);

 ds<<(qint32)20;

 ds<<bArray;

 qint32 code;

 ds>>code;
```

when i trace **ds>>code** it is always have 0 value but in fact it must have 20 value and i used **ds.resetStatus();** but it return 0 value again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `QDataStream::operator<<` functions sets some sort of pointer/iterator/index to point to the next location where they can start inserting data when the next call is made. `QDataStream::operator>>` probably starts to read from the same location.

`QDataStream::resetStatus()` does not change the position from where the object reads/writes. It merely resets the status to `QDataStream::Ok` to allow you to read from the stream after an error has occurred.

You can use two `QDataStream` objects -- one for writing to the `QByteArray` and the other for reading from the same `QByteArray`.

```
QByteArray byteArray;

QDataStream ds_w(&byteArray,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream ds_r(&byteArray,QIODevice::ReadOnly);

ds_w << (qint32)20;

ds_w << bArray;

qint32 code;

ds_r >> code;
```

Comment: ty R Sahu your codes worked too but i used ds.device()->reset();

Comment: note that you can use [`ds.device()->seek()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#seek) to point to wherever you want (not just the beginning of the stream).